# Calculate time difference by conditions Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Trying to get the activity time in an array object of a collection.

```
{
"id": "64f142e1d224858b66c9d987",
"Log": [{ 
"status": "Start",
"time": "09/02/2023 06:17:51",
"ISOdate": "2023-09-02T00:47:51.420Z",
},{
"status": "Hold",
"time": "09/02/2023 06:17:57",
"ISOdate": "2023-09-02T00:47:57.701Z",
}, {
"status": "Holdrelease",
"time": "09/03/2023 07:17:11",
"ISOdate": "2023-09-03T01:47:11.662Z",
},{
"status": "pause",
"time": "09/03/2023 07:21:11",
"ISOdate": "2023-09-03T01:51:11.662Z",
},
{
"status": "pauserelease",
"time": "09/03/2023 07:38:11",
"ISOdate": "2023-09-03T01:58:11.662Z",
},
{
"status": "Finish",
"time": "09/03/2023 07:59:46",
"ISOdate": "2023-09-03T02:29:46.841Z",
}]
}
```

**But the Hold and Holdrelease , pause and pauserelease may occur multiple times**

<--Expecting an output,-->

```
totalTime = (FinishTime - StartTime )

holdTime = total hold hours
pauseTime = total pause hours
workTime = totalTime - holdTime - pauseTime
```

I'm a newbie to mongodb so had tried my hands on with indexOfArray to match the status of the object and get the time to calculate.

But as i have mentioned above object array is dynamic.

No Idea how to approach the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do it in two steps without unwinding and grouping again:

1. Use `$reduce` to calculate the "hold" hours difference between each `Holdrelease` and its previous `Hold`. calculate the `totalTime` by the first and last log items.
2. `project` to format your response and calculate the `workTime`

The `$reduce` is using an object including the `totalHold`, `isHolding`, and `holdingSince` fields, and update them (using `$mergeObjects`) according to each `Hold`and `Holdrelease` items on the `Log` array, as it is looping over these items.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      totalTime: {$dateDiff: {
              startDate: {$first: "$Log.ISOdate"},
              endDate: {$last: "$Log.ISOdate"},
              unit: "hour"
      }},
      holdTime: {$reduce: {
          input: {$filter: {
              input: "$Log", 
              as: "item",
              cond: {$in: ["$$item.status", ["Hold", "Holdrelease"]]}
          }},
          initialValue: {
            totalHold: 0, 
            holdingSince: {$first: "$Log.ISOdate"}, 
            isHolding: false,
          },
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$eq: ["$$this.status", "Hold"]},
                  {$cond: [
                      {$eq: ["$$value.isHolding", false]},
                      {holdingSince: "$$this.ISOdate", isHolding: true},
                      {}
                  ]},
                  {totalHold: {
                      $add: [
                        "$$value.totalHold",
                        {$dateDiff: {
                            startDate: "$$value.holdingSince",
                            endDate: "$$this.ISOdate",
                            unit: "hour"
                        }}
                    ]},
                    isHolding: false
                  }
              ]}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      totalTime: 1,
      holdTime: "$holdTime.totalHold",
      workTime: {$subtract: ["$totalTime", "$holdTime.totalHold"]}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VY5TZQO2HR5)

Comment: Can you please explain the above code.

Comment: Added an explanation on the answer